# Choose a PDF Android Need Help! Not Getting Actual path

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gallery

I am Trying to choose a PDF from android SD card like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setType("application/pdf");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Documents"), DOCUMENT_SELECT_PDF);
```

This code returns me the URI of the selected PDF file something like this

URI Value

```
content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3D420
```

**Can you guys help, how I can get actual path from this URI?????????**

Rest Of code is Here

```
   case DOCUMENT_SELECT_PDF:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                final Uri pdfUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                documentFilePath = DocumentHelper.getPDFPath(this, pdfUri);
                if (documentFilePath != null) {
                    documentName = DocumentHelper.getFileName(documentFilePath);
                    documentMimeType = DocumentHelper.getMimeType(this, pdfUri);
                    uploadDocuments();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        break;
```

Comment: what do you need that path for?

Comment: I need to upload it ???

Comment: I am able to get the path from Image file but not from pdf so strange???

Comment: I don't think you need a path to upload pdf

Comment: can you help with a guideline. I need to convert to base 64

Comment: Do you need path of pdf?

Comment: yes the real path, already tried almost all the sample over internet might be I am doing something wrong :(